# Is it possible to call lightdm without logout?

Tags: 13.04, lightdm

So I'm making a video tutorial about ubuntu, but my VirtualBox wont load lightdm, and I would like to show it in the video.

is there a way of calling it from My installation of Ubuntu without logging out the session so I can keep recording?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method I was able to display the running lightdm login while running my session, is logging in to another session from the fast user switch in (which will probably be the guest session):

[image]

As soon as we log out from this session we will be brought back to the lightdm login screen where our still running session is marked with a triangle on the left side:

[image]